# Rxjs: What scenario do you want to use scheduler

Tags: javascript, scheduler, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I don't understand what does it mean by scheduler in rxjs documentation, so I'm trying to understand by scenario its useful in, so I can understand scheduler

Comment: I recorded the whole rxjs6 video course. Schedulers is one of the topics I review there: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video

Answer (score 9):

**&tldr;**

In most cases you will never need to concern yourself with `Schedulers` if only for the fact that for 90% of the cases the default is fine.

**Explanation**

A `Scheduler` is simply a way of standardizing time when using RxJS. It effectively *schedules* events to occur at sometime in the future.

We do this by using the `schedule` method to queue up new operations that the scheduler will execute in the future. How the `Scheduler` does this is completely up to the implementation. Often though it is simply about choosing the most efficient means of executing a future action.

Take a simple example whereby we are using the `timer` operator to execute an action at sometime in the future.

```
var source = Observable.timer(500);
```

This is pretty standard fare for RxJS. The `Scheduler` comes in when you ask the question, what does 500 mean? In the default case it will equal 500 milliseconds, because that is what the convention is and that is what the default `Scheduler` will do, it will wait 500 milliseconds and then emit an event.

However, there are cases where we may not want the flow of time to operate normally. The most common use case for this is when we are testing. We don't actually want to wait 500 milliseconds for a task to complete, otherwise our test suite would take ages to actually complete!

In that case we would actually want to control the flow of time such that we don't have to wait for 500 milliseconds to elapse before we can verify the result of an stream. In this case we could use the `TestScheduler` which can execute tasks synchronously so that we don't have to deal with any of that asynchronous messiness.

```
let scheduler = new TestScheduler();

//Overrides the default scheduler with the default scheduler
let source = Observable.timer(500, scheduler);

//Subscribe to the source, which behaves normally
source.subscribe(x => expect(x).to.be(0));

//When this gets called all pending actions get executed.
scheduler.flush();
```

There are some other more corner cases where we want to alter the flow of time as well. For instance if we are operating in the context of a game we would likely want to link our scheduling to the `requestAnimationFrame` or to some other faux time scale, which would necessitate the use of something like the `AnimationFrameScheduler` or the `VirtualTimeScheduler`.

---

Answer (score 0):

1. Scenario 1

you have initial value and want subscriber to get first initial value and then get some other value (depanding on condition).

```
const dispatcher = (new BehaviorSubject("INITIAL"))
.pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler));

let did = false; // condition

dispatcher.pipe(
  tap((value) => {
        if(!did) {
            did = true;
            dispatcher.next("SECOND");
        }
    }))
    .subscribe((state) => {
        console.log('Subscription value: ', state);
    });

   //Output: Initial ... SECOND
```

Without .pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler)) it will output vise-verse since Subject .next is sync operation.

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxzgwO?editors=0012)